# Simple Google script to copy contents of column A to column B?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, copy-paste

I feel like this should be pretty simple but I can't find anything on here or online that copies the full column and moves it to a different column WITHIN THE SAME SHEET. I don't need other criteria other than copy the data in column 'A' and paste that data into column 'B'.

Please advise if you can!

Thanks.

Comment: That's not at all what I want to do.

Comment: In B1 couldn't you just put `=A1` and drag B1 all the way down?

Comment: Yeah I certainly could but I need it to run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure why I got downvoted for this but I figured out how to simply copy from one row to another:

```
function copyValuesOnly() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getRange('List!C2:C10');
source.copyTo(ss.getRange('List!D2'), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: I didn't have the code. The only code I had to go off of was one I was playing around with to copy a row of data to another sheet at .getlastrow and that wasn't what I needed/wanted at all. Thought it would be a simple answer but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Below script should help you out. After pasting it in the script editor, run the onOpen function first. It should create an extra menu-item in your spreadsheet from where you can run the copy function.

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Copy Col A', 'copyCol')
    .addToUi();
}

function copyCol() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
ss.getRange('A:A')
    .copyTo(ss.getRange('B:B'), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```